# tcp connections for a webpage vs server load and speed

Tags: linux, apache, sockets, tcp

I would like to know how tcp connections are established when a webpage is accessed. When I access a webpage, and check the tcp connections under netstat, I see like 22 connections (with TIME_WAIT status) from same ip on first load. They all disappear a min after if no more page is accessed.

So it seems Apache webserver establishes one connection for each object like images and code on the page. So less objects or images on the webpage will make less connection and probably faster load time. 
Please correct me if my assumption is wrong.

What I want to know is how it affects the server load. Will less connections (webpage with less objects) reduce server load? How this number of tcp connections relate to number of httpd processes which will take up sever memory and resources. Upon inspection, using `ps -e httpd` process number does not seems to vary much with number of connections. What affects the httpd process count?

Answer (score 0):

KeepAlive and KeepAliveTimeout:

The KeepAlive directive allows multiple requests to be sent over the same TCP connection. This is particularly useful while serving HTML pages with lot of images. If KeepAlive is set to Off, then for each images, a separate TCP connection has to be made. Overhead due to establishing TCP connection can be eliminated by turning On KeepAlive.

KeepAliveTimeout determines how long to wait for the next request. Set this to a low value, perhaps between two to five seconds. If it is set too high, child processed are tied up waiting for the client when they could be used for serving new clients.